# Suma maxima con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo tres *inputs*, al agregar un valor se genera la suma de los tres *inputs* y luego muestro el resultado, el caso es que la suma debe de tener un valor máximo, de modo que si la suma máxima es de 10 y en los primeros *inputs* pongo 3 y 5 en la última debería de auto-rellenarse con 2 para que la suma total sea de 10, es para un ejercicio.

Éste es mi código:

```js
function sumar (valor) {
     var total = 0; 
     valor = parseInt(valor); // Convertir el valor a un entero (número).
     total = document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML;
     // Aquí valido si hay un valor previo, si no hay datos, le pongo un cero "0".
     total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;
     /* Esta es la suma. */
     total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));
     // Colocar el resultado de la suma en el control "span".
     document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
 }
```

```html
<span>Valor #1</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" onchange="sumar(this.value);" />
<br/ >
<span>Valor #2</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_2" onchange="sumar(this.value);" />
<br/ >
<span>Valor #3</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_3" onchange="sumar(this.value);" />
<br/ >
<span>El resultado es: </span> <span id="spTotal"></span>
```

Pero no se como podría implementar esa función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola no estoy seguro si te entendí, pero te hice un ejemplo de más o menos como seria, agregue jquery para que sea mas fácil. (el código tiene comentarios). Aqui no valido si el texto ingresado no es número.

```js
    let ValorMaximo = 10;

//Funcion que se activa cuando el valor de un input cambia
$("input").change(function(){
    
    //Verificar que tengan valor el texto 1 y 2
    if ($("#txt_campo_2").val() == "") {$("#txt_campo_2").val("0")}
    if ($("#txt_campo_1").val() == "") {$("#txt_campo_1").val("0")}

    //Obtener su valor
    let txt1 = parseFloat($("#txt_campo_1").val());
    let txt2 = parseFloat($("#txt_campo_2").val());

    //Si la suma del txt1 y 2 es menor al valor maximo se resta
    if (txt1 + txt2 < ValorMaximo) {
        $("#txt_campo_3").val(ValorMaximo - (txt1 + txt2))
    }else{ 
        $("#txt_campo_3").val("0");
    }

    let txt3 = parseFloat($("#txt_campo_3").val());

    //Sumamos todos los valores y los mostramos
    $("#spTotal").text(txt1 + txt2 + txt3);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<span>Valor #1</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_1"/>
    <br/ >
    <span>Valor #2</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_2" />
    <br/ >
    <span>Valor #3</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_3"/>
    <br/ >
    <span>El resultado es: </span> <span id="spTotal"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, es justo lo que necesito, no habia pensado en usar jquery pero es una solucion para mi asi que me parece perfecto, gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: De nada :)  que bueno que te sirvio.